# Multiple form validation: where to put $ajax when valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have multiple forms on a page and I'm trying to validate them with jQuery. The validation section is working, however, I can't figure out where to put the ajax if the form is valid.

Update: I have no idea how many forms there will be as these are dynamically generated.

```
<p><a href="">reload</a></p>

<div id="messages">
    <div id="message">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</div>

<form action="#" method="post" class="form">
    <select name="foo" class="required">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="bar" class="required">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form action="#" method="post" class="form">
    <select name="foo" class="required">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="snafoo">Snafoo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="bar" class="required">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$('.form').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler:function(form) {

            var foo = $(form).find('select[name=foo]').val();
            var bar = $(form).find('input[name=bar]').val();

            form.submit();
        },
        rules: {
            foo: {
                required: true
            },
             bar: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            foo: {
                required: 'Please select a foo'
            },
            bar: {
                required: 'Please enter a bar'
            }
        },

        errorContainer: $('#messages'),
        errorLabelContainer: $('#messages ul'),
        wrapper: 'li',

        // callback functions to work with bootstrap
        highlight:function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight:function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }

    });
});

// if the form is valid, do some ajax...
$('.form').on('submit', function(){
    if($(this).valid()){

        // testing...
        alert(foo);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'script.php',
            data: 'foo=' + foo,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                // do stuff...
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current place?

Comment: @oleg: it doesn't work. No alert, nothing...

Comment: No alert because `foo` is undefined. Just look into developer console for sometimes ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo` is undefined in your `submit` event. Need to add the following string:

```
$('.form').on('submit', function(){
    var foo = $('select', this).val();
    ...
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work, as it only returns the value from the first form.

Comment: So you should do the same for the second form ;-)

Comment: The same what? I updated the question; I have no idea how many forms there will be as these are dynamically generated from a database loop.

Comment: Perfect! it's always the obvious things that slip right past. Thanks :)